# Assume that all sets are subsets of a universal set $U$. For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, $A \cap (B-C) \subseteq (A\cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is my answer correct or did I not prove it very well?

> Use an element argument to prove the following statement. Assume that all sets are subsets of a universal set $U$.
>
> For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, $A \cap (B-C) \subseteq (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$.

Suppose that $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $A \cap (B-C)$.

$x \in A \cap (B-C)$

$A \cap (B-C) = \{x \mid x \in A \land x \in (B-C)\}$, by definition of intersection

$B-C = \{x \mid x \in B \land x \notin C\}$, by definition of difference of sets

Since,
$x \in A$ and $x \in B$, but $x \notin C$

then,
$x \in A \cap B$

$x \notin A \cap C$

So,
$x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$, by definition of difference of sets

therefore, by definition of subset
$x \in A \cap (B-C) \subseteq (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$

Comment: Correct........

Comment: Correct, **BUT** you could give a better explained reasoning for your conclusion that $x \notin A \cap C.$

Comment: How can I explained it in more detail?

Comment: For example, suppose $x \in A \cap C.$ Then $x \in A$ and $x \in C\colon$ this is a contradiction since by hypothesis, $x \notin C.$ Thus, $x \notin A \cap C.$

Comment: okay got it. thankss